# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. I've tried AbortController, but it aborts before async function is finished

Tags: reactjs

I seem to be getting a Unmounted Component but i don't know whats wrong.
I've seen tutorials but i really didn't understand.
I feel that they were a bit confusing so I hope you guys can fix it.
Here is my code.

```
import { Modal, Button, Row, Col, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Sidebar from '../../templates/sidebar';

const Pupils = (props) => {
    const [ pupils, setPupils ] = useState([ 1 ]);
    const onChange = (e) => setInputs({ ...inputs, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    const [ inputs, setInputs ] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: '',
        name: '',
        user_type: 'Student',
        class_id: props
    });
    const ab = new AbortController()
    const { username, password, name, user_type } = inputs;
    const [ modalShow, setModalShow ] = useState(false);
    const onSubmitForm = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const class_id = props;
        try {
            const jwt = localStorage.getItem('token');
            const body = { name, password, user_type, jwt, class_id };
            const response = await fetch('/auth/addpupil', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            });
            const parseRes = await response.json();
            console.log('hi' + parseRes);
            window.location.reload();
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    };

    const getPupils = async () => {
        try {
            console.log('processing');
            const jwt = localStorage.getItem('token');
            const body = { jwt, class_id: props };
            const resp = await fetch('/auth/getPupils', {
                signal: ab.signal,
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            });
            const jresp = await resp.json();
            setPupils(jresp.retInfo);
            console.log('pupils', pupils);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getPupils();
        ab.abort()
    }, []);
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Sidebar />
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => setModalShow(true)}>
                Add Pupil
            </Button>
            <Modal show={modalShow} size="lg" aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter" centered>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">Add Pupil</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <form onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
                        <label>Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name" onChange={(e) => onChange(e)} value={name} />
                        <br />

                        <label>Username:</label>
                        <input
                            name="username"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="username"
                            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                            value={username}
                        />
                        <br />

                        <label>Password:</label>
                        <input
                            name="password"
                            type="password"
                            placeholder="password"
                            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                            value={password}
                        />
                        <br />

                        <button className="btn btn-success btn-block">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button onClick={() => setModalShow(false)} className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                        Close
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
            <table className="table mt-5 text-center">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Word</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Play</th>

                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {pupils.map((pupil) => (
                        <tr key={pupil.user_id}>
                            {console.log(pupil)}
                            <td>{pupil.user_name}</td>
                            <td>{pupil}</td>

                            <td>
                                <button
                                    className="btn btn-primary"
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        let msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(pupil);
                                        window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
                                    }}
                                >
                                    Play
                                </button>
                            </td>
                            <td />
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </Fragment>
    );
};
export default Pupils;
```

Please can someone help me?
AbortController aborts before async function is finished .
If I don't use AbortController, I get

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

I will appreciate the help!
Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You are not awaiting the getPupils() call, which causes the abort to be triggered before the getPupils finishes. Also you don't need the AbortController, doesn't make any sense to abort the http request after it has been executed.

Comment: but now i get TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: `const jresp = await resp.json();
setPupils(jresp.retInfo);
console.log('pupils', pupils);
`
Does the api deliver an object having a collection named retInfo?
Also make that: `const [ pupils, setPupils ] = useState([ 1 ]);` initialize an empty array instead of 1.

Just debug it. Should not be that hard to figure out.